# Using nlargest to find winner of contest

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I am having issues with nlargest in pandas. I can't seem to figure out why the columns for each name aren't sorting properly. nlargest only seems to work on the first column even if the second or third column has the higher scores. I am tryin to find the winner based off of who has the highest two scores. In the example below Jeff should be the winner but nlargest only applies to the first column so dan always wins. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Sample Code:

```
import pandas as pd

names = []
con = int(input("Number of Contestants: "))
maxSurfers = con #number of surfers
while len(names) < maxSurfers:
        name = input(" Enter your Name: ")
        names.append(name)
        print("Contestants")
        print(names)
else:
       print("Thank You for Participating!\n")
       print("Sign up is now closed\n")

score = {}
for name in names:
    numWaves = int(input("Number of Waves for "+name+": "))
    newScores = []
    for i in range(numWaves):
        newScores.append(float(input("Enter score wave: ")))
    score[name] = newScores
#newScores - most recent entry committed to score directory

df = pd.DataFrame(score)
for (columnName, columnData) in df.iteritems():
    winner = df.nlargest(2, names)
print(winner)
```

Outputs:

```
Number of Contestants: 3
 Enter your Name: dan
Contestants
['dan']
 Enter your Name: jeff
Contestants
['dan', 'jeff']
 Enter your Name: eric
Contestants
['dan', 'jeff', 'eric']
Thank You for Participating!

Sign up is now closed

Number of Waves for dan: 5
Enter score wave: 3.0
Enter score wave: 10.0
Enter score wave: 5.6
Enter score wave: 9.5
Enter score wave: 3.0
Number of Waves for jeff: 5
Enter score wave: 10.0
Enter score wave: 3.0
Enter score wave: 3.0
Enter score wave: 9.9
Enter score wave: 3.0
Number of Waves for eric: 5
Enter score wave: 3.0
Enter score wave: 1.0
Enter score wave: 5.6
Enter score wave: 9.5
Enter score wave: 6.3
    dan  jeff  eric
1  10.0   3.0   1.0
3   9.5   9.9   9.5
```

Desired Output:

```
Number of Contestants: 3
 Enter your Name: dan
Contestants
['dan']
 Enter your Name: jeff
Contestants
['dan', 'jeff']
 Enter your Name: eric
Contestants
['dan', 'jeff', 'eric']
Thank You for Participating!

Sign up is now closed

Number of Waves for dan: 5
Enter score wave: 3.0
Enter score wave: 10.0
Enter score wave: 5.6
Enter score wave: 9.5
Enter score wave: 3.0
Number of Waves for jeff: 5
Enter score wave: 10.0
Enter score wave: 3.0
Enter score wave: 3.0
Enter score wave: 9.9
Enter score wave: 3.0
Number of Waves for eric: 5
Enter score wave: 3.0
Enter score wave: 1.0
Enter score wave: 5.6
Enter score wave: 9.5
Enter score wave: 6.3
    dan  jeff  eric
0   3.0  10.0   3.0
3   9.5   9.9   9.5
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that `df.nlargest` with a list of columns (for the parameter `columns`) will first sort based on the first value in the list (dan), then by the second (jeff) and finally eric.

It is explained at the end of the documentation page for `nlargest`:

[pandas.DataFrame.nlargest](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.nlargest.html)

To get the highest two values for each column try in this way:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(score)

winner_df = pd.DataFrame()
for (columnName, columnData) in df.iteritems():
    winner = df.nlargest(2, columnName)[columnName].reset_index(drop= True)
    winner_df[columnName] = winner

print(winner_df)
```

Output:

```
    dan     jeff    eric
0   10.0    10.0    9.5
1   9.5     9.9     6.3
```

Comment: Awesome, thank you! You've set me in the right direction. However, I am unable to get the same results when testing the code you suggested. How were you able to get it to work without defining df? Also I'm assuming that the .reset_index(drop= True) is what references each column without hard coding the names of each contestant. Is that correct?

Comment: you have to define df as in your code, mine was just and addition. Reset_index is needed just to make the winner_df rows all with the same index. Hope this helps

Comment: Okay that's what I thought and did but when I run the code I and print winner, only the last contestant is displayed. Sorry I've been coding for less than a week all of this is pretty new to me.

Comment: No problem :)  Try to print `winner_df` instead of `winner` at the end of the for loop (see the updated answer)

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I changed the code.

Changed to:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(score)
winner_df = pd.DataFrame()
for (columnName, columnData) in df.iteritems():
    winner = df.nlargest(2, columnName)[columnName].reset_index(drop= True)
    winner_df[columnName] = winner
print(winner)
```

Which outputs:

```
Number of Waves for dan: 3
Enter score wave: 3.0
Enter score wave: 3.0
Enter score wave: 3.0
Number of Waves for jake: 3
Enter score wave: 10.0
Enter score wave: 9.9
Enter score wave: 3.0
Number of Waves for jeff: 3
Enter score wave: 4.0
Enter score wave: 3.0
Enter score wave: 5.0
0    5.0
1    4.0
Name: jeff, dtype: float64
```

Note sure what is wrong.

Comment: just do `print(winner_df)` instead of `print(winner)`